# Removing the property values from all test cases of a test suite in SoapUI?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have 108 test cases in a test suite.
In each test cases, it has certain properties starts with `r_` (means it is a return variable from other test case). I want to remove all the property values which starts with `r_`.

I can do this by `TearDown Script` in each test case. But, it takes lot of time.

Is it possible from doing the same from Suite level `TearDown Script` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Below is the suite level `TearDown Script`.

```
//Define the pattern of property names which you want to clear the values
def pattern = 'r_'
//Loop thru each case of the suite and find those matching properties and clear them
testSuite.testCaseList.each { kase ->
    def props = kase.propertyNames.findAll { it.startsWith(pattern) }
    def msg = props ?: 'None'
    log.info "Matching properties for ${kase.name} test are : ${msg}"
    props?.each { prop -> kase.setPropertyValue(prop, '')}
}
```